# Which version of Terminator 2 shows an old Sarah Connor in the future?

Tags: terminator-2-judgment-day, the-terminator-series

I think I read somewhere that there was a scene in Terminator 2 that showed a glimpse from the future with an old Sarah Connor.  It's obviously not in the normal theatric version, but perhaps it's in the director's-cut or special-edition of the movie...

So my questions are; is there such a scene, what happens in it, and which version of the movie is it actually in?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you're referring to this deleted coda scene which was released in the extended "Special Edition", "Ultimate Edition" and "Extreme DVD" versions.

It shows an elderly Sarah watching children play (presumably at the playground in her earlier dreams) and talking about John having grown up to become a senator.

It is considered non-canon since it directly contradicts the events detailed in Terminator 3.

Comment: ... directly contradicts the events detailed in Terminator 3? Blasphemy. T2 > T3.

Comment: @Omegacron But Claire Danes... oh, who am I kidding? That movie sucked.

Comment: They made a Terminator 3?

Comment: I don't know about the other special editions that phantom42 refers to, but on the Ultimate Edition DVD that I had, you would never find this extended cut with the alternate ending if you didn't know the secret.  [It's a pretty well-hidden Easter egg.](http://www.eeggs.com/items/17011.html)  It's worth watching not just for the ending, though--there are a half-dozen other additions ranging from single shots of a few seconds, to added FX, to whole scenes.

Answer (score 0):

The scene in question was a deleted out-take (is that the right film term?) restored in the special edition and the director's cut of *T2:Judgement Day*. You could say it showed one *possible* outcome of a *possible* future had the Skynet Project stopped dead in its tracks after the destruction of Cyberdyne, Inc.